# "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to make a program that gets the "name" field out of the json file:

```
{
  "accounts" : {
    "fd1c3f81187b4a12b8e1226b0177a23basw" : {
      "accessToken" : "",
      "Profile" : {
        "id" : "ca227f281b6e40eebcb4fa9ef6c326fawedsa34",
        "name" : "random name"
      },
      
      "userProperites" : []
    }
  }
}
```

with the following code:

```
import json

json = json.loads('data.json')
accounts = json["accounts"]
    
for value in json["accounts"].values():
    print(value["name"])
```

but i am getting the "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" error, how can i make it work?

Comment: Please read the docs for `json.loads`. That is **not** how you tell it to read the content of a file

Comment: Also, naming a variable and an imported module with the same name is asking for problems

Comment: use `json.load` instead and do `json.load(open('file_path_goes_here', 'r'))`

Comment: @GurbakhshishSingh Using `json.loads` is ok if used correctly. Also, you should `open` a file using `with`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `.loads()`, it's looking for the json as a string. So you need to ready in the json file

```
import json

# JSON file
with open('data.json', "r") as f:
    jsonStr = f.read()
    jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)
    
accounts = jsonData["accounts"]
        
for value in jsonData["accounts"].values():
    print(value["name"])
```

Or

```
with open("data.json", "r") as f:
    jsonData = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Let's use `with` to promote best practices